# How to install libsvn-dev for mesos from git on OS X mavericks

Tags: macos, mesos

The getting started page doesn't explain much but to say "install like you would for ubuntu, here are those instructions." Other questions also never covered the problem of finding this package for OS X although I'll probably run in to those issues later as well.

I'm not really having mind blowing issues, but I'm using brew and I can't get the equivalent libsvn-dev package installed.

I installed subversion by running `brew install subversion --universal` and a search of brew packages didn't reveal anything with `libsvn` in the name. I'm sure there will be other packages I need to fight to install as well.

This is my ../configure message:

```
...(snip)....
checking for backtrace in -lunwind... no
checking for gzread in -lz... yes
checking for curl_global_init in -lcurl... yes
checking apr_pools.h usability... yes
checking apr_pools.h presence... yes
checking for apr_pools.h... yes
checking for apr_initialize in -lapr-1... yes
checking svn_version.h usability... no
checking svn_version.h presence... no
checking for svn_version.h... no
configure: error: cannot find libsvn_subr-1 headers
-------------------------------------------------------------------
libsubversion-1 is required for mesos to build.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I installed subversion by running `brew install subversion --universal` and a search of brew 
>   packages didn't reveal anything with `libsvn` in the name.

You should be able to see `subversion` with the `brew list` command.

The issue is that `configure` is trying to find the headers in `/usr/include`, but `homebrew` doesn't symlink them to `/usr/include`, but rather into `/usr/local/include`.

Try providing the `--with-svn` flag to `configure` like so:

`../configure --with-svn=/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.10_1`

#### Update

The build script has been updated and there's no need to provied the `--with-svn` flag anymore. You can now simply run `../configure`.

Comment: How do you do it WITHOUT using brew?

Answer (score 0):

It still shows the same issues with 0.22.0

libsubversion-1 is required for mesos to build.